# PHP-Laravel5 except csrf from another website

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I've tried to exclude requests from another localhost server (http://localhost:8080/order/placeorder) to another one localhost server (http://localhost:8000)
I don't want to disable all csrf protection by removing 
`\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class` in `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php`

I've tried to modify app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
protected $except = [
    'http://localhost:8080/*',
    'http://localhost:8080',
    '/order/placeorder/*',
    'http://localhost:8080/order/placeorder'
];
```

and I also tried this way

```
private $openRoutes = [
    'http://localhost:8080/*',
    'http://localhost:8080',
    '/order/placeorder/*',
    'http://localhost:8080/order/placeorder'
];

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //add this condition
    foreach($this->openRoutes as $route) {

        if ($request->is($route)) {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }

    return parent::handle($request, $next);
}
```

But I still got this error

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php

Can anyone suggest me what should I do and what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exceptions are routes within your own application that are excluded, not the URLs of servers that are requesting it. You will never put `localhost`, `http`, or any domain in these exceptions in normal circumstances. If you wish for a request by an external server to be accepted, I would disable CSRF protection for the routes it is accessing (because you want a cross-site request, that's what CSRF prevents).

For example, if you want **any** external server to be able to send a POST request to `/order/placeorder`, you would simply add that route to the exclusion. You also need to add any other route you want it to be able to access. If there are a lot, there are other more manageable ways to do this with middleware as well.

To authenticate the server making the request, it should send a token to verify itself. You can create a static token for this purpose (like an API key), or possibly use an OAuth implementation of some sort with access/refresh tokens - there is a package for Laravel for this that makes it easy.

Comment: hi, can you help me on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291960/laravel-disable-csrf-token-for-single-route